# iBeacons app send a lot notifications in background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, notifications, ibeacon

I had write an iBeacon app, that send notifications when the user is near the beacon(s). It works, but it sends a lot notifications! For example, I have one iBeacon near my phone and it sends me a lot of notifications(~10-15 notifications in a minute)

How can I send just one alert notification for each ibeacon every hour?

I'm ready to show my code you, but just say me which part of code do you want to see?

This is whole my
[AppDelegate.swift](http://pastebin.com/6HT3xVye)

Comment: You should be called once a second.

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag(property) to keep the `proximityUUID` or `CLBeacon` that have alerted notification , remove them if they are not in region.

```
// property
var myUUIDs: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

// didRangeBeacons
if (!myUUIDs.containsObject(nearestBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString)) {
    myUUIDs.addObject(nearestBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString)
    sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(message, playSound: playSound)  
}

// remove uuid not in beacons
for var i = 0; i < beacons.count; i++ {
    var beacon = beacons[i] as! CLBeacon
    if (!myUUIDs.containsObject(beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString)) {
        myUUIDs.removeObject(beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain how to do it, please?